# How to output PHP result in plottable format

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, d3.js, plotly

I am trying to use https://plot.ly/javascript/ for plotting `PHP` output from a `MySQL` database.  I need the output to be formatted like this -

```
var data = [
  {
    x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    y: [20, 14, 23],
    type: 'bar'
  }
];
```

This is currently the code I am using to get my output -

```
#PHP
$x = array();
$y = array();

while($query_result = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $x[] = $query_result['Animal'];
    $y[] = $query_result['Count'];
}

print_r($y);


#Javascript
$.get('../assets/php/Animals.php', function(data) {
    Plotly.newPlot('AnimalChart', data);
});
```

But it returns the data like this -

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 14
    [2] => 23
)
```

I've also tried to `json_encode` like this -

```
$rows = array();

while($query_result = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $query_result;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

But the output is this, which does not match the format expected for the plot -

```
[{"Animal":"giraffes","Count":"20"},
 {"Animal":"orangutans","Count":"14"},
 {"Animal":"monkeys","Count":"23"}]
```

In both scenarios, `Plot.ly` returns an error, which is why I think it needs to be formatted like the first example.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectAll' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is not just `$x` you need something like:

```
$x = array();
$y = array();

while($query_result = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $x[] = $query_result['Animal'];
    $y[] = $query_result['Count'];
}

$data = [ [
   "x" => $x,
   "y" => $y,
   "type" => "bar"  
] ]; 

echo json_encode($data);
```

Your JS also needs to use the correct dataType:

```
$.get('../assets/php/Animals.php', null, function(data) {
    Plotly.newPlot('AnimalChart', data);
}, "json");
```

Comment: What is the purpose of 'null' in the JS?

Comment: [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) accepts 4 parameters, `url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] ` I know jQuery is usually smart enough to infer which parameters you're sending by their values, but I like to be more explicit to be 100% sure. `null` corresponds to the `data` parameter, which your PHP script does not require.